# Ansible 2.9.10 error: "msg" "Invalid become method specified, could not find matching plugin: 'disable'

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

While running a YML Ansible Playbook, I get the following error.

```
fatal: [192.168.0.120]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Invalid become method specified, could not find matching plugin: 'disable'. Use `ansible-doc -t become -l` to list available plugins."}
```

My Ansible file is quite simple

```
- name: CONFIG FGT HOSTNAME AND INTERFACE
  hosts: FortiManager
  connection: httpapi
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:

  - name: CONFIRM AUTHORIZE UNAUTHORIZED FMG DEVICE
    pause:
      prompt: "Do you want to add FGT-ISFW as an authorized device?"
      echo: "yes"
```

I run the "ansible-doc -t become -l" commmand, but I don't see anything related to the msg message and am unsure what to do next.

```
# ansible-doc -t become -l enable
ksu        Kerberos substitute user
pbrun      PowerBroker run
enable     Switch to elevated permissions on a network device
sesu       CA Privileged Access Manager
pmrun      Privilege Manager run
runas      Run As user
sudo       Substitute User DO
su         Substitute User
doas       Do As user
pfexec     profile based execution
machinectl Systemd's machinectl privilege escalation
dzdo       Centrify's Direct Authorize
```

Any suggestions? I am running Ansible 2.9.10

```
# ansible --version
ansible 2.9.10
  config file = /home/fortinet/downloads/FMG-Ansible-Testing/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/opt/ansible/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15) [GCC 7.3.0]
```

Comment: Please check any of these locations if a "become" method is defined there: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/general_precedence.html#general-precedence-rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: *"FAILED! => {"msg": "Invalid **become method** specified, could not find matching plugin: '**disable**'.}"*

A: According to the error message, it's a [misconfiguration](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/executor/task_executor.py#L776). There is no *`disable`* [become plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/become.html#plugin-list). For example, this is wrong

```yaml
    become_method: disable
```

To disable [privilege escalation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#understanding-privilege-escalation-become) use [DEFAULT_BECOME](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-become). For example (this is the default)

```yaml
    become: false
```

The hard part is to find where the misconfiguration comes from. You're looking for [*DEFAULT_BECOME_METHOD*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-become-method). Take a look at the configuration

```sh
shell> ansible-config dump --changed-only
```

If it's not there take a look at inventory, group_vars, and host_vars. Search *`become_method`*.

Comment: I am looking through that now. Am I missing some plugin or something? The inventory is only one device (Fortinet FortiManager )

Comment: It seems [Fortimanager](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/networktocode/fortimanager-ansible/master/examples.md) does not need privilege escalation. The default is `become: false`. You can safely remove all become_* configuration.

Comment: Thanks. What confuses me here is that there are no “become” keywords on there.

Comment: It must be somewhere. Review all potential sources. See [Precedence categories](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/general_precedence.html#precedence-categories).

Comment: There are in my host file:   

ansible_network_os=fortimanager
ansible_become=no
ansible_become_method=disable

Comment: Bingo! This is the error you've been looking for `ansible_become_method=disable`. Simply remove it. `ansible_become=no` is default.

Comment: Ok, removed it (then got new errors) with the rest of the script.  Thank you for the assist here!